# Python - How to call a function from class that called this function

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have the following definition setup in my class MainWindow(QMainWindow) which calls a form (ToDo_Form) to populate a portion of the screen (mostly to keep my main file from getting huge from all the pages I'll eventually create).

```
    def show_chores_home(self):
        self.setStyleSheet('')
        self.chores_page = QVBoxLayout()
        self.chores_page.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        Form = QWidget()
        Form.setStyleSheet('')
        from chores_todo import ToDo_Form
        ui = ToDo_Form()
        ui.setupUi(Form)
        self.chores_page.addWidget(Form)
        
        self.scroll = QScrollArea()
        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setWidget(Form)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scroll)
```

Once inside ToDo_Form I show the list of all chores needing completed and allow for marking a chore as complete. My question is: Once everything has been completed for marking the chore done how do I return back to show_chores_home from inside ToDo_Form again so that the page will be reloaded with the now completed chore removed from the list/view?

In summary, I'd like:
Call show_chores_home, loads form, mark a chore as done, reload show_chores_home. But I don't know how to get back out to the MainWindow from within ToDo_Form

Comment: Never call `setCentralWidget()` more than once unless you really know what you're doing. If you need to switch between "pages", use QStackedWidget.